# MAMP Apache Server - One Subdirectory Works, Another Doesn't

Tags: apache, configuration, mamp, httpd.conf, htdocs

I am running an Apache server through MAMP.

I have two directories inside htdocs: TWS and SHR

SHR and TWS are two totally separate wordpress installations each with their own .htaccess files (which were previously working).

The .htaccess files are identical except TWS is replaced by SHR

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /TWS/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /TWS/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My problem is that localhost:81/TWS is accessible while localhost:81/SHR returns a 500 error.

apache/httpd.conf contains a directory for htdocs

```
<Directory "F:\MAMP\htdocs">
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and the DirectoryIndex is set to use index.html or index.php.
Both TWS and SHR have an index.php file at their root level.

I have checked all of the logs that I can find related to apache, php, mamp, and even mysql. None of the logs indicate an error.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was just a simple syntax error in one of the PHP files that I was editing.
The error got logged inside the wordpress log itself rather than the MAMP php logs.

That is, MAMP/htdocs/SHR/wp-content/debug.log

Once I resolved the php syntax error, everything worked fine again.